# How to evaluate a condition only if the previous condition returned true in Firestore security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my firestore security rules, on Update of a document, I want to **evaluate a condition first, and only if it returns true, then evaluate another condition**, which in my case happens to make an access call.

For example, I check **if the document which triggered the security rule:**

1. **has the field** `type` == `confidential` (condition returns `true` or `false`)
2. **If the previous condition returns true, THEN ONLY I want the check the field 'UserType' in the User object, who is currently updating the document**, by making an **access call.**

So if `type` is `not confidential`, i.e. **if the first condition fails, in that case I DO NOT WANT TO MAKE THE ACCESS CALL in the second condition**, as it **LIMITS MY BATCHED WRITES**.

Is there any way that **I can CHECK THE SECOND CONDITION (i.e. make the access call) ONLY IF THE FIRST CONDITION IS SATISFIED**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called a "boolean AND" operator, and it's documented for Firestore security rules [in the reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Boolean).

Pretty much all AND operations in all modern languages will "short circuit" in the way that you describe.  That is to say, the evaluation for the boolean will stop if one of the conditions is false, and continue only if the a condition is true, going from left to right.

```
allow read: if firstCondition() && secondCondition() && thirdCondition();
```

This will allow ready only if each boolean condition is true, and it will stop if any is false.

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot for clearing this. One more thing, would the batch write limit of 20 be still applicable even though the first condition fails and the security rule never reaches to the access call condition?

Comment: Batch limits are not at all related to security rules.  If a rule rejects any write, it doesn't count against anything.

Comment: But the documentation specifies that for a Batch Write or Transaction, the maximum number of access calls that can be made for the whole batch is 20. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_call_limits

Comment: You're only spending accesses on what the rules actually do.  Again, short circuited rules never execute and they don't count against anything.